Faithful action of $C_{pq}$ on a set of size $p+q$
Let $G$ be a group of order $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes such that $p\mid q-1$. Up to isomorphisms, there are two such groups, only: $C_{pq}$ and $C_p\ltimes C_q$. While I clearly see where the embedding of the latter into $S_q$ comes from$^\dagger$, I can't see where the embedding of the former into $S_{p+q}$ arises from, in the following sense:
Q: What is a set of size $p+q$ which $C_{pq}$ acts faithfully on, and how is this action defined? By "a set" I mean one whose elements are $G$-related objects (subgroups, elements, cosets, etc. of it), just like $G/P$ is for the $C_p\ltimes C_q$ case.

$^\dagger$The $G$-action by left multiplication on the left quotient set $G/P$, where $P$ is any $p$-Sylow subgroup.

For example $C_3 \times C_5 = \langle (1,2,3),(4,5,6,7,8) \rangle < S_8$. This action is intransitive. The smallest degree transitive action of $C_p \times C_q \cong C_{pq}$ has degree $pq$.

If you ask "where this action on $p+q$ points come from?" the immediate reaction is "Because 1. $C_{pq} \cong C_p \times C_q$ and 2. $C_n$ acts on $n$ points in an obvious way".
But then you ask specifically for an action on $G$-related objects. This is essentially an application of the orbit-stabilizer theorem, which says that a transitive action is isomorphic to the action by left multiplication on the cosets of a point stabilizer. To that end, decompose the above action into its orbits (which are both transitive, hence subject to orbit-stabilizer).
In the present situation the stabilizers are $C_p \subset C_p \times C_q$ and $C_q \subset C_p \times C_q$. Let $X = (C_p \times C_q)/ C_p$ and $Y = (C_p \times C_q)/C_q$. Then the given action is isomorphic to the action on $X \cup Y$ by left multiplication..

Could we rephrase as follows? Let $x,y\in C_{pq}$ have order $p$ and $q$ respectively. Let $C_{pq}$ act by left multiplication on $S:={g_i\langle x\rangle,h_j\langle y\rangle;i=1,\dots,q\text{ and }j=1,\dots, p}$ of size $p+q$. The action is faithful as the kernel is $\langle x\rangle\cap\langle y\rangle={1}$. (Incidentally, the action is clearly intransitive, as also pointed out by @DerekHolt above.)

I assume you mean to take $g_i = y^i$ and $h_j = x^j$. If so, then yes that is the same as the above construction, since the subgroup $C_q \subset C_p \times C_q$ is generated by any order $q$ element, and likewise for $C_p$.

Frankly i didn't think much of it, I just meant arbitrary coset representatives. Isn't that sufficient?

Well, you want to make sure you exhaust all cosets of $\langle x \rangle$ and $\langle y\rangle$. With the initial formulation (which doesn't define $g_i, h_j$) it's possible that $g_1$ and $g_2$ represent the same coset of $\langle x \rangle$. You could also say "let $g_i, h_j$ be distinct representatives of the cosets $G/C_p$ and $G/C_q$ respectively". I think it's clear that you mean this; I just wanted to point it out because you specifically asked if it was a valid rephrasing.
